# jQuery page navigation - with submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add jQuery page navigation to an internal website.

I have a text input:

```
<input id="nav" type="text"/>
```

And some jquery:

```
$("#nav").keydown(function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 74) {
                window.location = 'page1.html'; // Key = J
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 75) {
                window.location = 'page2.html'; // Key = k
            }
            else if (e.keyCode == 76) {
                window.location = 'page3.html'; // Key = L
            }

        });
```

This directs the user to a new page when a single key is pressed.

Is it possible to do the same thing, but with entire words, and requiring the `Enter` key be pressed?

**Example:**
If the user types `admin` into the text box, and then presses `enter`, the user is redirected to `admin.html`.

I would assume that it would need to be handled differently, but I am not sure how, or if it can be done.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let the user enter anything in the text box.

```
$("#nav").keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode !== 13) { // 13 = Enter
        return;
    }
    switch ($(this).val()) {
    case "admin":
        location.href = "admin.html";
        break;
    case "terms":
        location.href = "terms.html";
        break; // etc
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I was wanting to accomplish. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had to wait five minutes before it would let me :) I will now.

Answer (score 3):

This might help you. The function will check if the `keycode == 13` (code for Enter Key) and if the input value is `admin`, it will do the redirect.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/mrSF8/)

```
$("#nav").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var inputVal = $("#nav").val();
        if (inputVal === "admin") window.location = 'admin.html';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a form, and bind to its submit event. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from being submitted, and use an `if` statement to check which word was entered. Redirect to the correct page exactly as you're doing now.